# Highstock plotbands label not being hidden

Tags: highcharts

I recently migrated a highcharts spline with Y plotbands to highstock. Now, all labels for plotbands show (ones off the graph stack on eachother at the top of the graph) regardless of whether or not the plotband is within the graph.

![Highstock stacking plotband labels][1]

```
plotBands: [{ // Low
from: 0,
to: 299,
color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
label: {
    text: 'EXCELLENT',
    style: {
        'fill': 'rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.15)',
        'font-size': '441%;',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'text-shadow': '1px 1px 1px #8D9093, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 0px 2px #BEBEBE'
    }
}
(more plotbands with same formatting)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwbmu9ts/

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? With static data if necessary? Thanks.

Comment: updated question. Notice the overlapping text (which only occurs when using highstock)

Comment: I think it's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3989). Manwhile, downgrade to 2.1.1 version of Highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/gwbmu9ts/1/